# I need to save all pandas rows data to a specific field in JSON

Tags: python, pandas

I have a done some processing on data with pandas. Now I have it in the pandas dataFrame object. I need to save in in JSON. But my requirement say each row should be in the field called 'item'.
eg.

```
[{
  'item': row_1
},
{
  'item': row_2
},{
  'item': row_2
}]
```

row_1 is {'column1':'data11', 'column2':'data12'}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the to_dict('records') method on your dataframe in order to get a list of records. Assuming you have two columns and three rows (as shown above), the resultant record list will look like

```
[{'column1': 'data11', 'column2': 'data12'}, 
 {'column1': 'data21', 'column2': 'data22'}, 
 {'column1': 'data31', 'column2': 'data32'}]
```

Then you can iterate through this list of dicts to create a list with the required format. Altogether this looks like

```
# get the list of records from the original dataframe df
record_list = df.to_dict('records')

# use a list comprehension to get the record list in the desired format
formatted_list = [{'item': record} for record in record_list]
```

Comment: thanks to_dict() function  is what I was looking for

Answer (score 0):

Use [to_json()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_json.html):

```
df.to_json('data.json', orient='records', lines=True)
```